# Jupyter directory navigation at the browser level by pasting a path

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm in Jupyter Notebook.  I need to move around directories at the BROWSER level.  I'm working in the Terminal.  I can copy the long path from the terminal.  Then I want to paste it somewhere at the Jupyter Notebook level to get to that directory.

NOT in code, or in the terminal.  But back up at the browser level--in the explorer to the left.  I have to click-click-click-click to get anywhere normally.  But if I have large paths automated in the terminal, I want to just highlight them and paste them into Jupyter Notebook so the GUI goes there too.

How do I do that?

Thanks!